# Something's wrong with my reverse string function

Tags: c

So it seems it works when I reversed "hello", but it prints out something weird like 
"ol▒eh"
in the middle. It's gone when I fixed

```
i< length/2;
```

to

```
i<= length/2;
```

Isn't the first one supposed to be the right one?
what's the ▒ character mean in C? is it something like Null?

```
void reverse_copy(char dest[], const char src[]){
  size_t i;
  char temp;
  size_t length = (size_t)strlen(src);
  for(i = 0; i <= length/2; i++){ /*?? why i<length/2 is not working*/
    dest[i] = src[length-i-1];
    temp = src[i];
    dest[length-i-1] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. It should include how you call it, and what you pass for the arguments.

Comment: I also recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), as that's how one usually solves problem like that.

Comment: The loop would be simpler if you traverse its full length. Going half way is usual if you are reversing a string **in place** (otherwise it gets reversed twice), and in this case it does not matter if you skip the central character because it remains the same. Note too, you have not null-terminated the destination string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I was in a rush. I'll try to make it better next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem with `i< length/2;` is that it may leave out the "middle" element in case of odd string lenght of `src`. Hence, the middle element in `dest` may remain uninitialized, showing up as some "arbitrary" ASCII value then.

But in general, your code is appropriate for `reverse_in_place`, where you have to take care of not overwriting something that you need later in the loop for copying.

If you do a reverse_copy, however, it is sufficient - or better - to simply have one reverse loop:

```
void reverse_copy(char dest[], const char src[]){
  size_t i;
  size_t length = strlen(src);
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    dest[i] = src[length-i-1];
  }
  dest[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: By doing dest[i] = ‘\0’; , are you initializing the last index as null because that’s what the char array (string) in C supposed to have ? Like {h,e,l,l,o,’\0’} what does this line do to prevent from preventing?

Comment: I meant *crashing

Answer (score 3):

With :

```
for(i = 0; i < length/2; i++){
```

you never set the middle character (for odd lengths) in `dest`.

With your example `"hello"`, `length/2` is `2`, so you set (for `i` = `0`) :

```
dest[0] = src[5-0-1]; // dest[0] = src[4]
dest[5-0-1] = src[0]; // dest[4] = src[0]
```

and then (for `i` = `1`) :

```
dest[1] = src[5-1-1]; // dest[1] = src[3]
dest[5-1-1] = src[1]; // dest[3] = src[1]
```

and that's it. You never set `dest[2]`.

Comment: NMDV, yet "...and that's it" is incorrect as OP's code also lacks `dest[length] = '\0';

Comment: @chux : the "that's it" refers to what the OP's code does. It does no more - it doesn't set `dest[2]`, and you're right it also doesn't set `dest[5]`. I haven't mentioned the latter because it doesn't seem pertinent to the question (the OP asked about the character in `dest[2]` - presumably the `dest` buffer was already 0 initialized).

Answer (score 2):

Because `i<length/2` is already based on integer division, i.e: it will floor the result. This will skip the middle element in case of odd length strings.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is happening in the code, a debugger would help.
You need to step through the code line by line and watch what is the value of `i` and `length - i - 1`.

---

The reason a strange character appears in the middle is that if `length` is odd then the middle item is skipped when the condition is `<`.

For example, when `length == 5` then `5/2 == 2` (because of integer division `2.5` comes out to be `2` ).
So analysing the loop:

1. `i=0`
2. is `i < 2`. Yes, so continue code block.
3. `dest[0] = src[4]`
4. `temp = src[0]`
5. `dest[4] = temp`
6. `i++` i is 1
7. is `i < 2`. Yes, so continue code block.
8. `dest[1] = src[3]`
9. `temp = src[1]`
10. `dest[3] = temp`
11. `i++` i is 2
12. is `i < 2`. No, so exit the loop

So looking at the steps (especialialy steps 3,5,8,10) only `dest[0]`, `dest[1]`, `dest[3]`, `dest[4]` are written from the source when checking `<`.
Destination 2 is not changed.

This problem does not arise for even numbers.

---

As `dest[2]` was not updated then the character which was already there, is been displayed. Which could be any random character. If it was initialized to 0 (a null) then that is the character that represents 0.

But looking at that character it looks more like a value 177 (extended ASCII codes :http://www.asciitable.com/)

---

Also I find this definition of reverse_copy very error prone, as it it doesn't know how big the destination buffer is. It can overwrite something if it is too small.

---

In this case I would use a sentinel to mark the end of the string, and use a while loop:

```
void reverse_copy(char dest[], const char src[])
{
    const char* src_end = src + strlen(src) - 1;
    --src;

    while (src_end > src)
    {
        *dest = *src_end;

        ++dest;
        --src_end;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```